# How to spy class methods within nodejs modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, tdd, mocha.js, sinon

I have a simple module that exports a class:

```
function PusherCom(options) {
}

PusherCom.prototype.lobbyEvent = function(event, message) {
};

module.exports = PusherCom;
```

I require it from my `./index.js`:

```
var PusherCom = require('../comms/pusher');

function Play() {
  var pusher = new PusherCom();
  pusher.lobbyEvent('event', {});
}
```

I have a test for this app, problem is how can I mock `require('../comms/pusher')` class, or just the `lobbyEvent` method. Preferably with a sinon spy, so I can assert about arguments of `lobbyEvent`.

```
describe 'playlogic', ->

  beforeEach, ->
    pushMock = ->
      @lobbyEvent = (event, message) ->
        console.log event
      @
    // currently I tried proxyquire to mock the require but it doesn't support spying
    proxyquire './index.js, { './comms/pusher': pushMock }

  it 'should join lobby', (done) ->
    @playLogic = require './index.js'
    @playLogic.joinedLobby {}, (err, result) ->
      // How can I spy pushMock so I can assert the arguments
      // assert pushMock.called lobbyEvent with event, 'event'
```

How can I mock/spy a method within a class within some arbitrary module in nodejs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no javascript expert, but I'll take my chances anyway. Rather than spying the module, doing it in the `lobbyEvent()` method of the `pusher` instance, and injecting it into `Play()` would be a reasonable solution for your case? e.g.

```
// pusher.js
function PusherCom(options) { }

PusherCom.prototype.lobbyEvent = function(event, message) { };

module.exports = PusherCom;


// play.js
function Play(pusher) {
  pusher.lobbyEvent("event", { a: 1 });
}

module.exports = Play;

// play_test.js
 var assert    = require("assert"),
     sinon     = require("sinon"),
     PusherCom = require("./pusher"),
     Play      = require("./play");

describe("Play", function(){
  it("spy on PusherCom#lobbyEvent", function() {
    var pusher = new PusherCom(),
        spy    = sinon.spy(pusher, "lobbyEvent");

    Play(pusher);

    assert(spy.withArgs("event", { a: 1 }).called);
  })
})
```

HTH!

Comment: hm I see you, I have to refactor my code to write better test, does that improve the design of the code as well and how do I know that, I am newbie at writing code, so giving as argument a better approach?

Comment: I didn't quite get your question. Refactor your test? Well, actually you have to change it to work with my proposed solution. Better tests improve design? Most of the times, yes. Just happened here. You had a pain point in the test that led to a better design with less coupling between `Play` and `PusherCom`, now the latter being injected into the former. `Play` doesn't need to know how anything about `PusherCom`, all it needs is an object that responds to the `lobbyEvent` method. How you know its better? Loose coupling is one trait. The code will be easier to maintain and cope with changes.

Comment: thanks. Your solution worked well, in this case, but still I might not work for another use case, and I might need to solve my original problem, anyways I will wait a couple days, and accept your answer if anything better comes up, cheers.

Comment: Have you checked [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire)? It might solve your other cases.

Comment: Or you could simply override `lobbyEvent` with an spy in the `setup` phase of your test, run the assertions, and bring back the original `lobbyEvent` in `teardown`.